# How to detect the click in the Hyperlinks in Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Because now I want to add Google Tag Management in our site. We need to detect all the click actions in the Facebook SDK(for jQuery). 
I can detect the click action in "Like" button, use the code

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function() {
    dataLayer.push({'event': 'FacebookLike'});
});
```

But how can I detect the click in the Hyperlinks for user name, user image?